# Is an open TCP Port in C# secure?

Tags: c#, security, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I am sorry, this is kind of a noob question, but I don't get how ports work.
I think that when I open a tcp port in C# via the TcpListener on the server, anyone can connect to it. However, I only want my application client to connect to the port and send my predefined packets. Would it be possible for any person to connect to the port and send data that might harm my computer? Or is it just possible to send random data that is then just wrongly interpreted by my packet handlers?

I hope I could communicate my question clearly. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about the server side, but if you could just edit your post to clarify this, that would be great.

Comment: There are some preventive measures you can take to reject clients other than the ones you know are valid. On application layer you can apply IP restriction (check the remote IP and verify it against a white list of IP addresses you keep in your configuration), client certificates etc..

Comment: There are also some other measures on the network layer. A firewall can block all connections except the ones explicitly allowed to pass, or the server your application runs on can only be accessed through a leased line etc.. But by default, when you start listening on a port, there is no restriction as to who will connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Securing a port is generally a function of the operating system or the network infrastructure (could be as simple as a software firewall). You can use something like iptables to allow incoming connections from whitelisted IP addresses only.

If you want to do it through software, the server and client can use symmetric encryption. Only clients that know the key will be able to send meaningful messages. All other messages can be safely discarded.